# Determine level of bullet list entry

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a textbox in Powerpoint that contains a hierarchical list like this:

```
* Level 1
  - Level 2
    . Level 3
    . Level 3 again
  - Level 2 again
* Level 1 again
```

This is formatted as a bullet list.

Based on this text (which is an agenda), I'm creating a slide for every line with the line as the title:

```
Set shpSource = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
Set pre = ActivePresentation
Set sli = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1)

For Each varStr In Split(shpSource.TextFrame2.TextRange, vbCr)            
    Set sli = pre.Slides.AddSlide(sli.SlideIndex + 1, sli.CustomLayout)
    sli.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange = varStr
Next
```

My question is: How can I figure out, which level each bullet is?

Instead of only writing each line as title, I'd rather have something like `Level 1 > Level 2 > Level 3" as title, ie. some kind of breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, found the solution - each `Line` has `.ParagraphFormat.IndentLevel` that can be used. Here's the final code to convert a hierarchical list from a selected text box to new slides with breadcrumbs as titles:

```
Sub ConvertAgenda()
    Dim shpSource As ShapeRange
    Dim pre As Presentation
    Dim sli As Slide
    Dim trng As TextRange2
    Dim strL1 As String, strL2 As String, strFull As String, strCurrent As String

    Set shpSource = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    Set pre = ActivePresentation
    Set sli = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1)

    For Each trng In shpSource.TextFrame2.TextRange.Lines
        strCurrent = Left(trng, Len(trng) - 1)
        Select Case trng.ParagraphFormat.IndentLevel
            Case 1:
                strL1 = strCurrent
                strFull = strCurrent
            Case 2:
                strL2 = strCurrent
                strFull = strL1 & " > " & strCurrent
            Case 3:
                strFull = strL1 & " > " & strL2 & " > " & strCurrent
        End Select

        Set sli = pre.Slides.AddSlide(sli.SlideIndex + 1, sli.CustomLayout)
        sli.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange = strFull
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: A nice one!) I used `Indent` property in one great Excel solution once.